# Salesforce : create record with opportunity

Tags: php, salesforce

I can record a contact from php toolkit, now i should attach contact to an existing opportunity, is this possible with the same way as adding custom field?

```
$records[0] = new stdclass();$records[0]->FirstName = 'Irish';
$records[0]->LastName = 'Paul';
$records[0]->Phone = '(510) 555-5555';
$records[0]->myCustomField__c= 'value1; value2';
```

Now to attach this with opportunity, how should i do?

Thank you

Comment: Is it possible to add a contact to an opportunity throught contact ID and opportunity ID?

Comment: Or create opportunity from a contact? throught php

Comment: Did you get any solution yet?

Comment: $response = $mySforceConnection->create($records , 'Contact');